# Reference request for genus one Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I am learning Riemann surfaces on my own. Consider a torus, it is topologically a torus , but we can see extra insight by throwing in  complex analysis (i.e. topologically we have the torus, but now it as a genus one Riemann Surface).

I am looking for a reference about the complex analytic view of torus (i.e. the genus one Riemann surface). Also, which topics are covered in study of genus one Riemann surface?

Also, I have heard that elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ is an example of genus one Riemann surfaces. I am looking for a reference about genus one Riemann surface.

Please help me. Thanking in advanced.

Comment: The keywords are complex torus, complex elliptic curve, Weierstrass elliptic function, elliptic functions. Search any of these you'll get plenty of results. Good to see also that a compact Riemann surface with a non-vanishing holomorphic 1-form is biholomorphic to a complex torus, the biholomorphism being $p \to \int_{p_0}^p \omega$.

Comment: Elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ are *exactly* genus one Riemann surfaces (with a choice of point); they're basically the same thing.